# Java Regex Eliminate the last certain character to the end of string

Tags: java, regex

Pattern: `([^\|]*)`

Strings:

1. They found the the huge gold in Vietnam|China|Lao last summer.  | BBCworld.com
2. They found the the huge gold in Vietnam|China|Lao last summer.

Result: They found the the huge gold in Vietnam

Demo: http://regexr.com/3f8hi

Target:

They found the the huge gold in Vietnam|China|Lao last summer.

Comment: Question: How do you know it is OK to remove " | BBCworld.com" from string 1 but not OK to remove "|Lao last summer." from string 2? You must answer that question before we can answer your question.

Comment: P.S. @WiktorStribiżew it's not a duplicate, just poorly worded and poorly defined.

Answer (score 2):

A classic case of using regex where it's not needed:

```
String result = input.substring(0, input.lastIndexOf('|'));
```

Comment: I would say `indexOf`: The example says That for `They found the the huge gold in Vietnam|China|Lao last summer. | BBCworld.com` and `They found the the huge gold in Vietnam|China|Lao last summer.` the result should be `They found the the huge gold in Vietnam`, so it's the very first index of `|`, not the last one.

Comment: @BackSlash but the *desired output* is "They found the the huge gold in Vietnam|China|Lao last summer.".

Comment: Oh. So "Result" is what he is getting and "Target" is what he wants to achieve... My bad, but OP could have explained a little bit better. Sorry!

Comment: @BackSlash no problem, it's not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$` anchor, that means end of string:

```
\|[^|]*$
```